# Shoutcast/Icecast stream URL Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a function to check if an url is valid or not. But it says my stream url is invalid.

```
 Function IsValid_URL_Address(ByVal sURLAdd As String)

    Return Regex.IsMatch(sURLAdd, "^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?((/?\w+/)+|/?)(\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?")

    End Function
```

I want to validate urls like that:

http://www.someurl.com:8500/listen.pls

http://www.someurl.com:8500

http://someurl.com:8500/listen.pls

http://someurl.com:8500

It must begin with http or https.

Comment: The regex is ok, I think you need only to escape `/`-> `\/`. I tested the regex here -> http://regex101.com/r/sU8dU6 and it works. Given the error I think the problem is elsewhere, you should post the stacktrace of the exception thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
^(http|https):\/\/([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?$
```

[**Regex Demo**](http://rubular.com/r/0kLR67QLLb)

or:

```
/(http(s)?:\\)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+[.com|.in|.org]+(\[\?%&=]*)?/
```

[**Regex Demo**](http://rubular.com/r/HsjJuwBU7f)